# Get rid of the tooltip in contour plots

Tags: plotting

When I plot a curve using `ContourPlot`, and then move the cursor near the plotted line, a pop-up window (tooltip) with the corresponding function formula appears.

Very often I find it distracting, especially when the pop-up window is large and I want to get the coordinates.

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `ContourPlot`, `ContourLabels -> None`.

Comment: And can I disable this after I have done my plot?

Comment: @Agnieszka Try replacing `Tooltip` with `(#&)` in the output (see `ReplaceAll`).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your last comment. Assume that I have plotted ContourPlot[x^2+y^2==1,{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1}]. What should I do afterwards to prevent pop-up window?

Comment: Did you look up `ReplaceAll`?  `plot /. Tooltip -> (#&)`.

Comment: You should read about [graphics](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/08-basic-graphics-objects.html), see `Tooltip` (under Scope section in documentation page), `ReplaceAll`, and [pure functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) to understand why this works. I am assuming you already know that [everything is an expression](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html).

Answer (score 4):

@Agnieszka
The idea of Szabolcs can be used this way:

```
p = ContourPlot[x^2+y^2==1,{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1}];
p /. Tooltip -> (#&)
```

Pavel

Comment: Same as Szbolcs' comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155073/get-rid-of-the-tooltip-in-contour-plots#comment413889_155074

Comment: Yes, but Agnieszka did not understand his answer.

Comment: It would be polite to acknowledge Szabolcs' contribution, though, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you for the point.